# Connecting ESP8266 wifi module with Raspberry Pi zero to use home wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero, ubuntu, esp8266

I have been following 3 sources below where I could set up my Raspberry Pi zero with Wifi using ESP-01 (ESP8266) but am still struggling to get it working.

1. [Wifi configuration 1](https://desertbot.io/blog/setup-pi-zero-wifi)
2. [Wifi configuration 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VO4vGlQ1pg)
3. [Hardware connection](http://pwiatrowski.com/technology/raspberry-pi-zero-esp8266-internet/)

Eventually, I ended up using the approach shown in [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VO4vGlQ1pg) where the wifi connection is defined (SSID, PSK etc) in *wpa_supplicant.conf* instead of defined in */etc/network/interfaces* that has been proposed in [1](https://desertbot.io/blog/setup-pi-zero-wifi). What I did as well was to move the
*wpa_supplicant.conf* file in /boot directory instead of in the default directory SETTING and I don't think that would make any difference. Also, as per the hardware connection, I followed [3](http://pwiatrowski.com/technology/raspberry-pi-zero-esp8266-internet/).

At the moment, I keep on getting the error message below:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
```

after executing the command below in order to access the Pi:

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

Another concern is about *dtbo* file (one that resides in /boot/overlays directory) for ESP8266, do I need one? If so, is there I can find it?

EDITED:

- Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- OS on Raspi zero: Raspbian
- `ip address` returns:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 44:1c:a8:e3:c6:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.160/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
   valid_lft 42797sec preferred_lft 42797sec
inet6 fd7d:42cf:4a81::10e/128 scope global dynamic
   valid_lft 86001sec preferred_lft 86001sec
inet6 fd7d:42cf:4a81:0:6f11:f3c8:5fcd:69f3/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic
   valid_lft 6800sec preferred_lft 1400sec
inet6 fe80::f13b:c028:5e97:d65b/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- `ip route` returns:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.160  metric 600
```

- `iw wlan0 link` returns usage info as wlan0 couldn't be found
- `ssh -v pi@192.168.1.160` returns:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alfa/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.160 [192.168.1.160] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alfa/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.160:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:FJdiiwb9zKALjlyyqX7bhdfdnGlmJU52FNDN9jjP1Eo
debug1: Host '192.168.1.160' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alfa/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alfa/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alfa/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alfa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alfa/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.1.160's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.160's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.160's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: You have 3 links but haven't explained **what YOU did**. No one should be expected to sit through youtube to guess. We don't even know what OS or what you are using to connect.

Comment: @alfa_80, Ah, let me see.  Your three tutorials are OK, and your final choice of (2) is good.  And if you follow (2), then you don't need (1), which is a bit out of date.  I sat through (2) and find the guy Macgyver as good as usual (I am his huge fan!)  His stuff is 2019 feb, so should be more or less updated (though I prefer buster). You need (3) to talk to ESP8266.  However, this (3) is 4 years old, so we need to check carefully if there are things outdated. / to continue, ...

Comment: @tifong01: That's a good hint. Thanks anyway. Please can you can a look whenever you got time :-)

Comment: @alfa_80, Just now I skimmed the JeeLab pages that you will be following.  I found the JeeLab guy seems retired, because his most recent blog post is 4 years old, and also his "JeeLab Esp8266  Link", also 4 years ago (though regularly updated, until 3 months ago.)  Anyway, I will skim though it and see if they are OK.  Lunch time.  See you later! Cheers.
(1) About JeeLabs - JeeLabs 2015 (most recent post)
https://jeelabs.org/about/

(2) JeeLab Esp Link - jeeLab 2019july (last update)
jeelabs/esp-link

Comment: @tlfong01: That's a good to know..Thanks

Comment: I've edited my post anyway to ask my concern that dtbo might be the culprit.

Comment: @alfa_80, Before I go, just to make sure, have you followed the tutorial and "grabed the JeeLab's esp8266-link firmware, and flashed it on your ESP8266"?  Without the firmware, you won't do anything! :)

Comment: @tlfong01: I thought the firmware is built-in as I can see the SSID of the ESP on my ubuntu. If that so, I will do it then. Do you have a good url for me to start with the firmware of it? What about "http://domoticx.com/esp8266-wifi-esp-link-firmware/"?

Comment: @tlfong01: Apologies. I've overlooked that you provided a link of Jee lab. That's cool..thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100406/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-alfa-80).

Comment: What is ESP8266? Do you use Raspbian or Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi? Can you please edit your question and add the output of this three commands to it: `ip addr`, `ip route` and `iw wlan0 link`.

Comment: @Ingo: I've just edited the information. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

From the information you have given so far it seems that the RasPi has a working WiFi interface **wlp2s0**. As shown by `ip addr` it has a dynamic ip address 192.168.1.160/24 that is usually given by a DHCP server on the network. So it must be connected to a remote access point and everything is good. The command `iw wlp2s0 link` would give us more details about the wifi connection. If you try from your host

```
host ~$ ssh pi@192.168.1.160
```

then it should do. From the debug output of `ssh-v` you have given in the question I can see that everything is working as expected. `ssh` tries `Authentications that can continue: publickey,password`. With publickey authentication you need the private key file on the ubuntu host but as shown there is no one (`Trying private key: /home/alfa/.ssh/id_rsa, ../id_dsa, ../id_ecdsa, ../id_ed25519` but not found). Now `Next authentication method: password`. You tried to enter a wrong password three times, then `ssh` gives up.

Please use the right password to login. It is the same password that you use to login on the console. The default password from installation is **raspberry**. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.  I didn't realize that OP's WiFi controller module ESP-01 is Domoticx's toy, with preflashed firmware to immediately talk to  Ubantu host.  I think now it is a RpiZW and ESP8266-01 communication problem.  JeeLab Rpi ESP serial link firmware might might make the job very simple, except it cannot sit in ESP's flash together with the Domoticx stuff already there.  I would suggest OP to forget JeeLab and chk out Domoticx (already talking with the host Ubantu) tools for RpiZW.  Just brainstorming - me no experience with Domoticx! :)

Comment: @Ingo:  Thanks Ingo for the answer. Just I'm yet to get it connected. It is now keep failing the authentication ("pi@192.168.1.160's password:") by returning "Permission denied, please try again." when I entered the password of "raspberry". Anyidea that I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Eventually, when after several attempts failed, it returns "Permission denied (publickey,password).
"

Comment: How do you login on the console with keyboard/monitor? Do you use pi/raspberry? Get more information from ssh with option `-v`: `ssh -v pi@192.168.1.160`.

Comment: I login with keyboard only (headless). I'm using raspberry pi zero anyway..the output with -v will come very soon

Comment: @Ingo:I've just updated the post.

Comment: @alfa_80 I do not understand. You cannot ssh into the RPiZero and you only have a keyboard attached to it. How do you see the output of `ip addr` you have given in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure about it as well, but I guess is there any possibility that it remembered the IP from the login session that I connect via USB last time? And what I observed, when I didn't ON the raspi at all, the ip addr stil outputs the same t IP as it would if I would connect to the SoC.

Comment: Your last comment is very confusing. What are you suddenly talking about an USB connection? Do you use in addition an USB OTG gadget connection? So you must have an additional interface but that isn't shown with `ip addr`. Anyway, I have updated the answer at the end. Please use the correct password.

Comment: @Ingo: I used to use USB over ethernet cable to talk to RasPi but since I wanted to test the wireless functionality, I didn't connect with the cable anymore. I doubt the password was the culprit as I tried with the default password more than 30 times. I would guess the IP set when I logged in was wrong.

Comment: @alfa_80 How do you login to the RasPi to take the output of `ip address`? Just use the same password for `ssh`.

Comment: The command that I output the ip address was done on the host btw, not on the host PC.

Comment: @Ingo: I think I really need to install the firmware on the ESP because when I tried with another version of RasPi (W version), I could ping directly "ping raspberrypi.local" and was getting the IP & communication as expected. I think I will stick to raspberry pi W for a while by now. Thanks anyway.